# Check animation state time - why doesn't work?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, state, animator

I need to disable object after its current animation (state in animator) is finished.
Why is it doesn't work?

```
if (myObject.GetComponent<Animator().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(1).normalizedTime == 1) {
myObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good idea to compare `float` directly like `normalizedTime == 1`. Just use `<` or `>=`. You can also use `Mathf.Approximately`.

Anyways, when you start an animation, start a coroutine function that checks if that animation is done. This prevents wasting time in the Update function to check when animation is done. That coroutine function should have a paramter that checks for the name of the animation.

```
IEnumerator OnAnimationComplete(string name)
{
    Animator anim = myObject.GetComponent<Animator>();

    while (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(name) && anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime < 1.0f)
    {
        //Wait every frame until animation has finished
        yield return null;
    }
    Debug.Log("Animation has finished");
    //Do something
}
```

**Usage**:

1.Start the animation.

2.Start the OnAnimationComplete coroutine: `StartCoroutine(OnAnimationComplete("JumpAnim"));`

---

There other ways to do this too such as using the [`AnimationEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationEvent.html) event. Check out the provided link for examples about this.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do like this:

```cs
Animator anim = myObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
anim.Update(0f);
float delay = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length;
Invoke("DoSomethingAfterAnimationFinished", delay);
private void DoSomethingAfterAnimationFinished(){
     ...
}
```

In this way you can execute anything after animation finished

Answer (score -2):

```
GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(1).normalizedTime == 1
//GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(1) i used 0 insted of 1 its just diff in layer
```

In my case:
`GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime` - will give u time since object is "alive" in scene (on which is animator ) till ur current state in animation.
So if u state in animation starts as soon as ur object is in scene it wont be :

```
GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(1).normalizedTime == 1
```

but:

```
GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(1).normalizedTime == 0.
```

This has nothing to do with if animation is played for 3 seconds or how long it is, if u use `GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(1).normalizedTime` as a condition check maybe use `Debug.Log(GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(1).normalizedTime );` to see  what it will return and use it as time u need to put in condition for ur case.